# PPSSPP save folder can't be found anywhere

Tags: linux

I can't find the PPSSPP saves folder anywhere. I searched online and many sources said that it could be found in .config/PPSSPP but i didn't found it there even when i viewed hidden files it wasn't there.If anyone can help it will be appreciated.I use linux mint 20.1.

Answer (score 1):

I found the file location. It was not in `.config` it was in

```
.var/app/org.ppsspp.PPSSPP/config
```